# Minus operation always returns positive value

Tags: javascript, rpn

I'm creating a method for an array like function RPNCalculator, but for some reason it does'n work correctly.

For example when I try to do operation 3 - 8 it will return 5 instead of -5, for 3 - 4 it will return 1 instead of -1. As you can see it inside of **num** variable.

I would really appreciate your help.

RPN is [2, 3 ,4]

```js
RPNCalculator.prototype.minus = function() {
 console.log("First item " + this[this.length - 2] + "\nLast Item " + this[this.length - 1]); 
        /* Logs:First item 3
                Last Item 4 */
 var num = this.pop(this[this.length - 2]) - this.pop(this[this.length - 1]);
 console.log(num);    // logs 1
 this.push(num);
};
```

Comment: Not sure about your implementation details, but maybe you need to do `var num = this.pop(this[this.length - 1]) - this.pop(this[this.length - 2]);`?

Comment: Note that you are logging `this[...]` but you are subtracting the *return value* of `this.pop(this[...])`. So what exactly does `this.pop()` return? What does it do? Why is it there? Seems like it might return the `length` of something.

Comment: Normally, [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) removes the last item in the array, returns that value and doesn't take any arguments. Does your implementation change that at all?

Comment: Guys, thanks for your help. i really appreciate it.

Comment: @MikeC, your thought was correct. pop removes the last item and returns it. 
`RPNCalculator.prototype.minus = function() {
  let lastNum = this.pop();
  let firstNum = this.pop();
  this.push(firstNum - lastNum);
};`
This fixed the problem. If you can answer this question below, I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're using [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop). `pop` removes the last item from the array and returns that last item. You should rewrite your function like this:

```
RPNCalculator.prototype.minus = function() {
  let lastName = this.pop();
  let firstNum = this.pop();
  this.push(firstNum - lastNum);
};
```